# Loopback 4: How to inject user in endpoint

Tags: loopback4

I have an endpoint where both users and guests (not authenticated) can post data to:

```
 async create(
    @requestBody({
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: {
            type: 'object',
            properties: {
              create_account: {type: 'boolean'},
              password: {type: 'string'},
              password_repeat: {type: 'string'},
              currency: {type: 'string'},
              payment_method: {type: 'string'},
              products: {type: 'array'},
              voucher: {type: 'string'},
              customer: {type: 'object'},
              news_letter: {type: 'boolean'},
            },
          },
        },
      },
    })
    @inject(SecurityBindings.USER) currentUserProfile: UserProfile,
    order: Omit<Order, 'id'>,
  ): Promise<{url: string}> {
       const userId = currentUserProfile[securityId];
  }
```

However, I am unsure how to get the logged-in user from the session as I am getting the following error:

```
The key 'security.user' is not bound to any value in context
```

How do I get the user id in this situation?

Comment: This most likely means that authentication wasn't set up properly for the endpoint. Please see https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Decorators_authenticate.html on how to use the authentication decorators.

Comment: To inject user, you need to decorate endpoint with `@secured`. Then the authentication service will set `security.user` which found from the token. The cause for the error is you have not decorated endpoint with `@secured` so no user bound for `security.user`. I suggest you to remove `@inject` from parameters and use request object to find either guest or user.

Comment: there doesn't seem to be an @secured decorator in lb4

Comment: Yes there is none. You need to create one. [Loopback documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Loopback-component-authentication.html) or [this](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Authentication-Tutorial.html) tutorial may help you. BTW, you cannot inject `user` unless you decorated the class or endpoint with **authentication decorator** as mentioned by @rifa-achrinza

Answer (score 3):

The controller endpoint needs to be decorated with the `@authenticate()` and `@authorize()` decorator and the authentication system must be set up beforehand.

The authentication and authorization documentation has been recently overhauled. Please refer to them as a definitive guide.

For example,

```js
  @post('/users/{userId}/orders', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'User.Order model instance',
        content: {'application/json': {schema: {'x-ts-type': Order}}},
      },
    },
  })
  @authenticate('jwt')
  @authorize({resource: 'order', scopes: ['create']})
  async createOrder(
    @param.path.string('userId') userId: string,
    @requestBody() order: Order,
  ): Promise<Order> {
    await this.userRepo.orders(userId).create(order);
  }
```

Unfortunately without more info (e.g. authentication strategy and authorization provider), it is not possible to give a definitive solution, as different UAA implementations will have different solutions.

### Further reading

- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Authentication-overview.html
- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Loopback-component-authorization.html